# How to modify an np.array like this?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an empty array

```
arr = np.array([])
```

Then I have a loop. At the beginning of each iteration I want to modify the array so that the next index in the array is an array of 4 arrays with 3 zeros in each of the 4 arrays. So the first iteration would look like this.

```
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]
```

second iteration:

```
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]
 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Do I have use `np.zeros` as the initial array and specify a size?
What modify methods should I use: concatenate, stack, etc?

Comment: Do you have any performance requirement?

Comment: That shape (0,) array doesn't do you any good.  It donesn't have space to insert or set anything.  Don't treat it like a empty list, `[]`.

Comment: you can't modify such array.  you can only make a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of iterations before-hand, then it is as simple as:

```
arr = np.zeros((number_of_iterations, 4, 3))
```

E.g.:

```
>>> arr = np.zeros((2, 4, 3))  #  only two iterations
>>> arr
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```